# Sql concatenate dropdownlist

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I'm having trouble pulling sql data when I concatenate my drop down list with two columns.  I would like to combine the Last Name (lName) + First Name (fName) and pull the data on those names.  Here is what I have so far.

```
 <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
        DataSourceID="SqlDataSource3"  DataTextField="lName" DataValueField="lName" 
        AppendDataBoundItems="True" 
        onselectedindexchanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
        <asp:ListItem Value="Select">Select</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>

  <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource3" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:TestDBConnectionString1 %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT (lName + fName) AS zName FROM CoaTest"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Then I have a formview with all the Databounds in it and it's sql connection looks like this:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:TestDBConnectionString1 %>" 
        DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [CoaTest] WHERE [Id] = @Id" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT Id, fName, lName, agency, title, gen, hired, AppS,
        course, Location, SessNum, SDate, EDate, Hours, SitUps, pushUps, rTime, 
        Grade FROM CoaTest WHERE (lName = @lName)"


        UpdateCommand="UPDATE [CoaTest] SET [fName] = @fName, [lName] = @lName, [agency] = @agency, [title] = @title, [gen] = @gen, [hired] = @hired, [AppS] = @Apps, [course] = @course, [Location] = @Location, [SDate] = @SDate, [EDate] = @EDate, [Hours] = @Hours WHERE [Id] = @Id">
        <DeleteParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="Id" Type="Int32" />
        </DeleteParameters>
        <SelectParameters> 
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DropDownList1" Name="lName"  
                PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" /> 

        </SelectParameters>
        <UpdateParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="fName" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="lName" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Agency" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="title" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="gen" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="hired" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Apps" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="course" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Location" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="SDate" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="EDate" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Hours" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Id" Type="Int32" />
        </UpdateParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

This works if I just have it pull by Last Name (lName) but when I try to concatenate it doesn't pull the data from the formview.  Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change select command for dropdown to `SELECT Id, (lName + fName) AS zName FROM CoaTest`, change dropdown's DataValueField value to `Id` and selecting data to FormView by Id instead of by name

Comment: Hi Yuriy Thank you for the fast response.  I went with the changes that you describe, but now it pulls up the people by numbers instead of Last Name / First Name.

Comment: @vadim Change `DataTextField` to `zName`

Comment: I think we are almost there. I'm getting this error now when selecting a name 'Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'BaileyJessica' to data type int.'

Comment: Opps sorry I messed up! It's working now, `<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
            DataSourceID="SqlDataSource3"  DataTextField="zName" DataValueField="Id" 
            AppendDataBoundItems="True" 
            onselectedindexchanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
        </asp:DropDownList>` 

@Yuriy Thank you so much for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

I think the `DataValueField` and the `DataTextField` properties should be as this:

- `datavaluefield ="zname"`, because the alias for the concatenate is named as zname no lname

Also you are not projecting or displaying the lname table column in you datasource query